# Abstract class' constructor asks for a return type

Tags: c#, constructor, compiler-errors

I don't understand what's happening here, I've copied this code from another project (which compiled without problems), but as soon as I got it into my own, I got a compiler error on the constructor definition saying the method needs a return type.

```
public abstract class BaseSqlRepository<T, InterfaceT, PrimaryKeyT>
        where T : class
        where InterfaceT : class
{
    protected EvalgridEntities DataContext;
    protected BaseSqlRespository(EvalgridEntities db)
    {
        this.DataContext = db;
    }
}
```

> Method must have a return type.

What am I missing?

Comment: Bah, how did that happen when I copy/pasted it!? ._.

Comment: No idea - but that's the problem (at least, it is if this is the real code...)

Comment: You probably pasted it fine, and placed your cursor in the middle of the word at some point and accidentally hit 's' on your keyboard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You misspelled it.  Your constructor is spelled BaseSqlRe **sp** ository.

Change to:

```
protected BaseSqlRepository(EvalgridEntities db)
{
    this.DataContext = db;
}
```

Since the naming is different, the compiler sees this as a method, not a constructor.  Since there is no return type, you get the error:

> Method must have a return type.

Answer (score 4):

You have a typo.  The name of your class is `BaseSqlRepository` (everything spelled correctly), but your constructor's name is BaseSqlRe*s*pository (extra s in the middle).

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your code.  The name of the class is BaseSqlRepository, but the name of the constructor is BaseSqlRe**S**pository.